# how to run gwt gae app on every browser?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

how is it possible to run a gwt app on all browsers?

when i put in my app_name.gwt.xml

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8" />
```

the app runs only on firefox

if i put

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />
```

it runs on google chrome.

if i put

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />
<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8" />
```

he takes the last value so the app runs only on firefox.

i have tried things like this

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8, safari" />
```

or

```
 <set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" value="gecko1_8"/>
```

but nothing works.
what to do that the gwt app runs on every browser?

Comment: What happens if you don't specify a user.agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the set-property tag or comment it out:

```
<!--set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8" /-->
```

Then the compiler will build all possible permutations (# of languages x 6).